# Android NDK search headers recursively

Tags: android, c++, path, header, android-ndk

how I can do the NDK search the headers in all folder?

for example it works:

```
#include "../../../CPPCore/Model/User.h"
```

but it no:

```
#include "User.h"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add header file path in the android.mk file

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += <PATH>/CPPCore/Model
```

checkout some links from android forum, it may help:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/-_scQd5leqo

Comment: I'm uses a makefile, Android.mk

Comment: perfect!! I only did one adjustement:: `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include` `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ${shell find $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../CPPCore/ -type d}`

Comment: how can I do that in gradle, not using the Make files, but using the new experimental gradle? I tried ldFlags.add("") and CFlags.add(" -I/app/src/main/jni/some")